# Need to make two model fileds as primary key

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Here profile and category should be primary key how can i do this.

```
class QuickApproximation(models.Model):
        profile = models.CharField(primary_key=True, null=False, max_length=1024, default=None)
        category = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=1024, default=None)
        approximation = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=None)
```

I need to dump this data into DB

```
Profile,Category,Approximations
Always on road,Groceries,500
Always on road,Dining,500
Always on road,Gas,500
Always on road,Others,1500
Social Butterfly,Groceries,500
Social Butterfly,Dining,500
Social Butterfly,Gas,500
Social Butterfly,Others,1500
Foodie,Groceries,500
Foodie,Dining,500
Foodie,Gas,500
Foodie,Others,1500
Pantry Stocker,Groceries,500
Pantry Stocker,Dining,500
Pantry Stocker,Gas,500
Pantry Stocker,Others,1500
Avid Shopper,Groceries,500
Avid Shopper,Dining,500
Avid Shopper,Gas,500
Avid Shopper,Others,1500
Healthy nut,Groceries,500
Healthy nut,Dining,500
Healthy nut,Gas,500
Healthy nut,Others,1500
Digital Junky,Groceries,500
Digital Junky,Dining,500
Digital Junky,Gas,500
Digital Junky,Others,1500
```

and everything should be available in db

Comment: I dont think you need profile and category to be `primary_keys` rather you want them to be [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

Comment: Handling compound primary keys has some challenges. You should stay with the auto generated `id` field if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must give primary_key to it field which you want.
I suggest you read this here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/

Answer (score 0):

Django does not allow compound primary keys. So you can only give the `primary_key=True` attribute to one field.